# iOS APP Error : The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier

Tags: ios

I recently created an iOS app on a computer and then switched to another computer. I was able to build the project and run it on an emulator or directly on my phone, but since I changed computer it is not working anymore.

The first time I tried to run it on my phone a message said : "Your certificate has been revoked"

The build succeeds but I have these error messages :

> The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier.

When I run the app on my phone.

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)

When I try to run the app on the emulator.

I tried many things to solve this problem such as, adding info.plist in "Build pathes", changing the bundle id, cleaning the project etc. But it still isn't working.

Does anybody have an idea ?

Thank you in advance,